# Quotient Topology in Bredon's Topology

Tags: general-topology

I was reading Bredon's Geometry and Topology, but I had trouble understanding example 13.9. The author defined the following: If $X$ is a space and $A\subset X$, then $X/A$ denotes the quotient space obtained via the equivalence relation whose equivalence classes are $A$ abd the single point sets$\{x\},x\in X-A$. This makes sense to me. Then the following example was given:

Consider the cylinder $S^n\times I$. Define $f:S^n\times I\rightarrow D^{n+1}$ by $f(x,t)=xt.$ This carries the set $S^n\times \{0\}$ to the origin and so $f$ factors through $S^n \times I/S^n \times \{0\}$. The resulting map $g: S^n \times I/S^n \times \{0\}$ is clearly bijective and thus it is a homeomorphism.

My question is, how is $f$ factors through $S^n \times I/S^n \times \{0\}$?  And what is meant by $I/S^n$? $S^n$ is not a subspace of $I$. Also, why the map $g$ is clearly bijective?

I am sorry if I have asked a dumb question. But I am very confused, thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no $I/S^n$. It is $(S^n \times I) / (S^n \times \{0\})$ without parantheses.

Comment: OMG i got it now! I was so stupid... Thanks Alex!

Comment: I notice that you have asked 5 questions, but you have not accepted any of the answers given to them (all of which that I find to be very good). This kind of attitude is discouraged here. If you persist in it, people will stop answering your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $D^{n+1} = \{ x \in \Bbb R ^{n+1} \mid |x| \le 1 \}$ and $I=[0,1]$.  Notice that every point $x \in D^{n+1}$ can be written as $t \frac x {|x|}$, with $t = |x| \in I$ and $\frac x {|x|} \in S^n$.

The above means that the mapping $f$ given by $S^n \times I \ni (x,t) \mapsto tx \in D^{n+1}$ is surjective. The problem is that all the points of the form $(x,0) \in S^n \times \{0\}$ are mapped to $0 \in D^{n+1}$, which breaks injectivity. In order to cure this, you make all these points "coincide", i.e you collapse them into a single point in a new space in which you "kill" $S^n \times \{0\}$, and the mathematical procedure that accomplishes this is the taking of the quotient $(S^n \times I) / (S^n \times \{0\})$. Call the points of this new space $\widehat {(x,t)}$. You construct a new map $g : (S^n \times I) / (S^n \times \{0\}) \to D^{n+1}$ from $f: S^n \times I \to D^{n+1}$ by $g (\widehat {(x, t)}) = \begin{cases} tx, & t \ne 0 \\ 0, & t = 0 \end{cases} .$

Since $f$ was surjective, so will be $g$. The lack of injectivity of $f$ has been fixed by the above procedure, so the resulting $g$ is now injective too, so it is bijective.

Notice that if $p : S^n \times I \to (S^n \times I) / (S^n \times \{0\})$ is the natural projection defined by $p(x,t) = \widehat {(x,t)}$, then $f = g \circ p$, and this is what is meant by "$f$ factors through $(S^n \times I) / (S^n \times \{0\})$". More clearly, $f$ can be written as a "product" (i.e. function composition)

$$\underbrace {S^n \times I \stackrel p {\to}  (S^n \times I) / (S^n \times \{0\}) \stackrel g \to D^{n+1}} _f ,$$

so, in a sense, $f$ passes "through" $(S^n \times I) / (S^n \times \{0\})$ which sits in the middle of the diagram.

Comment: @Aweygan: Fixed, thank you.